# In a Ant Junit task how to filter the real tests?

Tags: ant

This is my task. I want search all the Junit tests and output the results in one txt file.But this task found all the java files with "Test" in their names and output the results in separated files. How to modify it?

```
<target name="run_Junit" depends="compile_all">
        <junit printsummary="on">
            <formatter type="plain"/>
            <batchtest todir="${build_snapshot}">
                <fileset dir="src">
                 <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
                 </fileset>
            </batchtest>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="ivy.path" />
                <pathelement location="${build_classes}"/>
            </classpath>
        </junit>    
     </target>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear: are you trying to get all your JUnit test results in a single file (that's what your question text seems to imply), or are you only wanting to run classes that are actually tests, and not those with test in the name (which is what the title seems to imply)?

Answer (score 0):

The JUnit task doesn't support writing to a single file directly, but you could use the Ant [concatentate](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) task to merge all the test result text files into a single file after the Junit task completes.